# Nestjs/swagger: Complex Objects

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I was wondering if there's a way to support complex objects for Nestjs/swagger. I just finished the migration and I am now working on the swagger documentation. A lot of my requests return complex objects and I'm wondering if there's an easier way.
Example:

```
class Foobar{
  prop1: {
    subprop1: {
      subsub1: string;
    };
  };
}
```

Becomes:

```
class SubSub{
  @ApiModelProperty()
  subsub1: string;
}
class SubProp{
  @ApiModelProperty()
  subporp1: SubSub;
}
class Foobar {
  @ApiModelProperty()
  prop1: SubProp;
}
```

If I do this:

```
class Foobar{
  @ApiModelProperty()
  prop1: {
    subprop1: {
      subsub1: string;
    };
  };
}
```

I get this in swagger:

```
{
  "prop1": {}
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**UPDATE 04/2020**: `ApiModelProperty` now has been changed to `ApiProperty`

```js
    class SubSub{
      @ApiProperty()
      subsub1: string;
    }

    class SubProp{
      @ApiProperty({ type: SubSub })
      subporp1: SubSub;
    }

    class Foobar {
      @ApiProperty({ type: () => SubProp })
      prop1: SubProp;
    }
```

In the last `ApiProperty`, I used "Lazy Evaluated Function" syntax. This is to prevent Circular Dependency problem. Thought I'd add it in there.

---

```
class SubSub{
  @ApiModelProperty()
  subsub1: string;
}

class SubProp{
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: SubSub })
  subporp1: SubSub;
}

class Foobar {
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: SubProp })
  prop1: SubProp;
}
```

The `@ApiModelProperty` takes in an option object where you can specify the `type` if it's a complex object.

Comment: `@ApiModelProperty` has since been renamed to `@ApiProperty`

Comment: @ApiProperty({
    type: () => [SubProp],
  })
This is for array of object.

Comment: `@ApiProperty({ type: [SubProp] })` was the only way I got it working.

Answer (score 7):

```
class SubSub {
  @ApiProperty()
  subsub1: string;
}

class SubProp {
  @ApiProperty({ type: SubSub })
  subporp1: SubSub;
}
```

or if Array

```
class SubProp {
  @ApiProperty({ isArray: true,  type: SubSub })
  subporp1: SubSub[];
  //or subporp1: [SubSub];
}
```